# Doing a regex match on a string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Like many others, I'm crap at regex and particularly bad when it comes to regex in javascript.

I have a string that can take two formats:

```
var str = "This is a string t:1h"
```

or

```
var str = "This is a string t:1h,2h,3h"
```

I would like to match the 't:X' part or 't:X,X,X' part (whichever it happens to be) from the string and handle that separately.

Can anybody clever show me how to do a regex match on this string for this?

I haven't gotten very far. I have:

```
var reg = /\s?/m;
parsed = str.match(reg);
```

Please help.

Comment: You're missing the `/` at the beginning of the regexp.

Comment: In fact, it looks like almost all of your regexp is missing. Did you mess up copying into the question?

Comment: _"Like many others, I'm crap at regex and particularly bad when it comes to regex in javascript_" -- Regex are pretty universal, once you learn them you can use them pretty much in any language with minor variations. I'm sure many people including myself have learned here http://www.regular-expressions.info/.

Comment: Nope, I just haven't a clue what to put there :) Sorry about that. I'm learning as you comment.

Comment: Learning regex is an important exercise, and it's good that you're doing that.  But in *this* case, it's more power than you need.  You can get by adequately simply with `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("t:"))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
var test = "This is a string t:1h,2h,3h"
var matches = test.match(/t:.*/)
console.debug(matches[0])
```

Gives

```
t:1h,2h,3h
```

Comment: Yep! That's what I wanted. Thanks!

Comment: If you want more strict validation, use: var matches = test.match(/t:(\dh,?)*/)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
var str = "This is t:1h,2h,3h bla bla";
var reg = new RegExp("t:[0-9]h(,[0-9]h)*");
var parsed = str.match(reg)[0];
```

One could also use the "special-RegExp-writing" of Javascript:

```
var parsed = str.match(/t:[0-9]h(,[0-9]h)*/)[0];
```